# Generate Cesium 3-D tiles from shapefile with FME

Tags: shapefile, fme-form, 3d, cesium

I'm trying to generate 3-D tiles from a shapefile. Just simple shp reader directly to Cesium 3D tiles writer.  It does generate files,  but after uploading them to Cesium Ion it does not work.

It can't even generate preview of it.

Am I missing some step in FME?

[image]

Additional info:

While adding SHP reader I used "Read from source" option, that's why it is blank now:

[image]

while adding 3-D tiles writer I used "Same as source" option.

[image]

Settings of shapefile:

[image]

I also tried to use [EPSG:4326](http://www.epsg-registry.org/?display=entity&urn=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326) in both components but same result.

Comment: Why you leave Coordinate System blank? Check what coordinate system you need, and export tiles with that.

Comment: Are your shapefiles 3D? If not, you'll need to extrude the geometry or define the third dimension somehow.

Comment: Yes z values are required (if you don't have any you can create them using attribute creator). also 3DForcer will help > https://www.safe.com/blog/2018/10/visualizing-geospatial-data-web-browser-cesium-ion-fme/

Comment: I added more info regarding coordinates I used.

Comment: Next check. When you add tiles to Cesium you should add in what crs they are. Can you add some code from cesium with that tile source when you are added it to cesium?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you need to add the coordinate systems or the translation would return errors.